# Stuck ETHs in the contract

Tags: ether, etherscan

This is the contract as you see there's 4.4+ eth there

0x2193B9F2B5E5051E41C32c71B25587D6A6f045C8

I still have ownership of contract.

Any way of getting/extracting the eth from there using the creator account? WTG reward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, there is not a way for you to get the ether out of the contract. There are only 4 write functions (functions that modify the blockchain.) All of them do not transfer money out of the contract. There is a function that transfers money out of the contract but it is impossible to use it as it transfers the same amount that you put in.

Answer (score 0):

For getting out the tokens you had to implement a withdraw function. Now, it's too late.